# update with join on CTE doesn't use index, but with temp table it does

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Using postgres9.6. All statistics up to date, everything vacuumed and repacked.

We all know about 10% of the internet is devoted to "why isnt postgres using my index"....this is one of those

I have a table `session`, with index on primary key `id`. When I do the following update its slow (5+ minutes)

```
WITH session_cte as (

  --big complex cte, however the cte itself is FAST

)
update session S set S.foo = Z.foo
from session_cte as Z
where Z.id = S.id
```

Explain seen here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/FtI4
The culprit is the seq_scan at the bottom.

However when instead of a CTE I dump the result into a temp table and then join on that for the update its blazing fast, explain here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/W3c6

```
create temp table session_cte_temp AS ( 
   --same complicated SQL as in the CTE
 );
 update session S set S.foo = Z.foo
 from session_cte as Z
 where Z.id = S.id;
```

Can someone explain why the cte is tripping up the planner so badly? Why in the temp table case the correct index is chosen?

Comment: Postgres has more statistics about the temporary table, so it can choose a more reasonable execution path.

Comment: Does that mean it has absolutely NO stats on CTEs ?

Comment: It means that the stats on CTEs are estimated, because they are calculated during the compilation phase.  The stats on temporary tables should be more exact, because the table exists.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say it in so many words, but it looks like you ran `ANALYZE` on the temporary table, because the estimate of 1 row is spot an.

That makes the difference.

PostgreSQL runs the same query, regardless if it is a CTE or creates a temporary table, and that query is fast, as you correctly observe.

Unfortunately PostgreSQL's estimate of the number of rows found by that subquery is horribly wrong — I'll analyze (hint, hint!) the cause later on.

This wrong estimate is corrected by the creation of the temporary table and particularly the `ANALYZE`, so you end up with a good execution plan.

But let's take a step back.

Why is the misestimate so bad? The reason are the misestimates of the scans on `alias_staging_zml` and `session_fbc669c0_3cce_4322_83a6_8b80da7ed545`. So you should `ANALYZE` these tables, and that should change everything else.

If `ANALYZE` doesn't improve things, you might have to increase the statistics target for the column, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE session_fbc669c0_3cce_4322_83a6_8b80da7ed545
   ALTER person_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Comment: I actually did not run analyze on the temp table - but in the case of the explain it did contain one row in that particular example.  Your claim that "PostgreSQL runs the same query, regardless if it is a CTE or creates a temporary table" conflicts with Gordon's comment above. The other tables you mentioned are already analyzed - see my original question where I state "all statistics are up to date"

Comment: PostgreSQL never estimates 1 row for a new table where you added one row (try it), unless you change `autovacuum_analyze_threshold`. Your plans suggest bad estimates. Perhaps you should raise `default_statistics_target` before `ANALYZE`.

Comment: Looking again, I don't believe that you analyzed the tables. There is no way that a sequential scan on an analyzed table `alias_staging_zml` can estimate 240 rows when there is really only one. You must be confusing something.

Comment: Laurenz you are correct! When I run 'analyze alias_staging_zml' the query runs in less than a second!